# Execute .py file inside Django dir

Tags: python, django

I have a Django website that render a Dash app (dash is similar to flask), and inside my Django project i have an app folder and inside app folder is my .py file that contain my Dash app that works with "application/json" response.

This file .py contain all pandas logic and dash logic that manipulate data onces user upload new file.

The problem is:

This .py file run only when I start server "Python manage.py runserver".

How I can do to this .py be executed using a Django view.

I tried to include:

```
execfile(path)

Also:

f = open('/paths/file.py', 'r')
v = f.read()
eval(str(v))
```

But this not worked.

There are another way to execute a .py file that are inside some Django dir?

Comment: Take a look at writing custom commands: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/custom-management-commands/

Comment: You can also override the `ready` function of some `AppConfig`.

Comment: @Willem I will check it out and return, I basically need to use some existent view as a trigger.

Comment: I might be misunderstanding, but if you want to run a django script without starting the server you can run ```python manage.py shell script_file.py```